# Find my Bitcoin Account

Tags: lost-wallet

I signed up for Bitcoin many years ago and I have no clue on how to find my account. I googled "how to find my bitcoin account" and I got this platform. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as a Bitcoin account.

If you mean an account on a Bitcoin *exchange*, then I'd check your emails and maybe old bank statements from that time to see if you can find which exchange it is, then try and recover your account.

If you mean a Bitcoin *wallet*, and you have completely lost the wallet file and have no backup of its keys, then it is probably gone for good. You can try looking through your old computer backups if you have any; if you used the Bitcoin Core client you're looking for a file called wallet.dat.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful.